# XSLT Transformator - Call Template wrong position

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello community i have one XSLT and one XML which i want to convert into an other XSLT.

Script 1: Includes an Common.xslt where templates are stored.
Script 2: Common

When i run this xml the output is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Payload']">
        <xsl:variable name="countElements">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(//../SRBE)"/>
        </xsl:variable>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
<xsl:element xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" name="OperatorCode">
    <xsl:attribute name="type">Data</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="SRBE/OperatorCode"/>
</xsl:element>
```

but i need the output like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Payload']">
        <xsl:variable name="countElements">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(//../SRBE)"/>
        </xsl:variable>
<xsl:element xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" name="OperatorCode">
    <xsl:attribute name="type">Data</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="SRBE/OperatorCode"/>
</xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

SCRIPT 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:include href="common.xslt"></xsl:include>  
    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Mask']">
        <!-- set path -->
        <xsl:param name="path" select="./Interface"></xsl:param>
        <xsl:call-template name="common"></xsl:call-template>

        <!-- check if mask is an SRBE -->
        <xsl:if test="$mask = 'SRBE'">
            <!-- iterate over all Field elements -->
            <xsl:for-each select="$path/Field">
                <!-- set variable fieldName with exploded Field Name -->
                <xsl:variable name="fieldName">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(./@Name, '/')"></xsl:value-of>
                </xsl:variable>

                <!-- switch case start if maxoccurs is set or not -->
                <xsl:choose>
                    <!-- if maxoccurs is set and greater then 1 -->
                    <xsl:when test="./Son/@MaxOccurs and ./Son/@MaxOccurs > 1">

                        <!-- manually field sets -->
                        <xsl:if test="$fieldName = 'FreeFormatLine'">
                            <xsl:call-template name="tablePageBreak">
                                <xsl:with-param name="fieldName"><xsl:value-of select ="$fieldName"/></xsl:with-param>
                                <xsl:with-param name="wrapperName">Line</xsl:with-param>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:when>


                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <!-- call singleFields template -->
                        <xsl:call-template name="singleFields">
                            <!-- set params -->
                            <xsl:with-param name="fieldName"><xsl:value-of select ="$fieldName"/></xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>

                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

            </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

SCRIPT 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- set variable "MASK" with service name-->
    <xsl:variable name="mask">
        <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='Repository']/@Name"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- start of standart template ~Mask -->
    <xsl:template name="common">
        <!-- create pseudo stylesheet -->
        <xsl:element name="xsl:stylesheet">
            <xsl:attribute name="version">1.0</xsl:attribute>

            <!-- create pseudo xsl output with attributes -->
            <xsl:element name="xsl:output">
                <xsl:attribute name="method">xml</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="version">1.0</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="encoding">UTF-8</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="indent">yes</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="omit-xml-declaration">yes</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>

            <!-- create pseudo xsl template -->
            <xsl:element name="xsl:template">
                <xsl:attribute name="match">*[local-name()='Payload']</xsl:attribute>

                <xsl:element name="xsl:variable">
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">countElements</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:element name="xsl:value-of">
                        <xsl:attribute name="select">count(//../<xsl:value-of select="$mask"/>)</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>



            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template for table sbre output -->
    <xsl:template name="tablePageBreak">
        <xsl:param name="fieldName" />
        <xsl:param name="wrapperName" />

        <!-- pseudo foreach mask name tag | multiple e.g. SRBE'S-->
        <xsl:element name="xsl:for-each">
            <xsl:attribute name="select">//*[local-name()='<xsl:value-of select="$mask"></xsl:value-of>']</xsl:attribute>

            <!-- pseudo create variable | get position -->
            <xsl:element name="xsl:variable">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">srbeId</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="xsl:value-of">
                    <xsl:attribute name="select">position()</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>

            <!-- pseudo create variable | count all lines in mask name tag -->
            <xsl:element name="xsl:variable">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">lines</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="xsl:value-of">
                    <xsl:attribute name="select">count(./<xsl:value-of select="$fieldName"></xsl:value-of>)</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>

            <!-- pseudo create table wrapper -->
            <xsl:element name="xsl:element">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">Document</xsl:attribute>
                <!-- pseudo add type attribute with "Table" -->
                <xsl:element name="xsl:attribute"><xsl:attribute name="name">Type</xsl:attribute>Table</xsl:element>
                <!-- pseudo create DocumentType Number Element -->
                <xsl:element name="xsl:element">
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">DocumentTypeNumber</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:element name="xsl:attribute"><xsl:attribute name="name">type</xsl:attribute>Data</xsl:element>
                    <!-- pseudo fill DocumentTypeNumber with Information -->
                    <xsl:element name="xsl:value-of">
                        <xsl:attribute name="select">concat(../PrintHeader/barcode,../PrintHeader/ticketNo)</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
                <!-- pseudo for each -> iterate all fields -->
                <xsl:element name="xsl:for-each">
                    <xsl:attribute name="select">./<xsl:value-of select="$fieldName"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute>
                    <!-- pseudo create element with $fieldName as Tag -->
                    <xsl:element name="xsl:element">
                        <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="$wrapperName"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:element name="xsl:attribute"><xsl:attribute name="name">Type</xsl:attribute>Table</xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="xsl:element">
                            <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="$fieldName"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:element name="xsl:value-of">
                                <xsl:attribute name="select">.</xsl:attribute>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <!-- pseudo if: if not last mask element and if last subelement -->
                        <xsl:element name="xsl:if">
                            <xsl:attribute name="test">$countElements != $srbeId and $lines = position()</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:element name="xsl:element">
                                <xsl:attribute name="name">TurnPageAfter</xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:element name="xsl:value-of">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="select">number(substring-before(../Page, '/'))</xsl:attribute>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>

                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template for table output -->
    <xsl:template name="table">
        <xsl:param name="fieldName" />
        <xsl:param name="wrapperName" />

        <!-- pseudo foreach mask name tag -->
        <xsl:element name="xsl:for-each">
            <xsl:attribute name="select">//*[local-name()='<xsl:value-of select="$mask"></xsl:value-of>']</xsl:attribute>

            <!-- pseudo for each -> iterate all fields -->
                <xsl:element name="xsl:for-each">
                    <xsl:attribute name="select">./<xsl:value-of select="$fieldName"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute>
                    <!-- pseudo create element with $fieldName as Tag -->
                    <xsl:element name="xsl:element">
                        <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="$wrapperName"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:element name="xsl:attribute"><xsl:attribute name="name">Type</xsl:attribute>Table</xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="xsl:element">
                            <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="$fieldName"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:element name="xsl:value-of">
                                <xsl:attribute name="select">.</xsl:attribute>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>

                </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template for count up input fields-->
    <xsl:template name="countUp">
        <xsl:param name="fieldName" />

        <xsl:element name="xsl:for-each">
            <xsl:attribute name="select"><xsl:value-of select="$mask"/>/<xsl:value-of select="$fieldName"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="xsl:element">

                <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="$fieldName"/>_{position()}</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="xsl:attribute"><xsl:attribute name="name">type</xsl:attribute>Data</xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="xsl:value-of">
                    <xsl:attribute name="select">.</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template for single input fields-->
    <xsl:template name="singleFields">
        <xsl:param name="fieldName" />

        <!-- create element for creating fieldName element -->
        <xsl:element name="xsl:element">
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:if test="$fieldName != 'Page'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$fieldName"></xsl:value-of>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="$fieldName = 'Page'">Pages</xsl:if>
            </xsl:attribute>

            <xsl:element name="xsl:attribute">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">type</xsl:attribute>Data</xsl:element>


            <!-- create element for creating value-of -> fill content -->
            <xsl:element name="xsl:value-of">
                <xsl:if test="$fieldName != 'Page'">
                    <xsl:attribute name="select"><xsl:value-of select="$mask"/>/<xsl:value-of select="$fieldName"/></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="$fieldName = 'Page'">
                    <xsl:attribute name="select">number(substring-after(<xsl:value-of select="$mask"/>/<xsl:value-of select="$fieldName"/>, '/'))</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:element>

        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<Repository xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="SRBE" Version="1" Language="de">
<BOMTHeader PartnerName="PRNT" ExternalProtocol="XML" InternalProtocol="Datastream" RepositoryComment="" IdentifierNestingLevel="0" IdentifierType="P" VersionNestingLevel="0" VersionType="B" IdentifierElementValue="Name"/>
<STARTMasks>
<Mask lang="de" Name="SRBE" Version="1" Barcode="75" DynamicPrint="1">
 <Interface>
    <Service Name="SRBE" Version="1" NoSel="1">
      <Segment Name="TOPLEVELTAG" Version="01" OmtSort="1" UsedByOmt="1" />
      <Segment Name="PrintHeaderAcp" Version="01" OmtSort="2" UsedByOmt="1" />
      <Segment Name="PrintHeader" Version="01" OmtSort="3" UsedByOmt="1" />
      <Segment Name="SRBE" Mandatory="1" Main="1" OmtSort="4" UsedByOmt="1" />
    </Service>
<Field Name="SRBE/OperatorCode" >
 <Position Row="0" Col="2" Len="13" />
  <Son Name="vermittler_veran" SonSort="1" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/OperatorName" >
 <Position Row="0" Col="16" Len="30" />
  <Son Name="veran_text" SonSort="2" />
  <Printtype Big="1" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/TravelType" >
 <Position Row="0" Col="70" Len="8" />
  <Son Name="veran_reiseart" SonSort="3" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/OperatorStreet" >
 <Position Row="1" Col="16" Len="30" />
  <Son Name="veran_strasse" SonSort="4" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/OperatorCity" >
 <Position Row="2" Col="16" Len="30" />
  <Son Name="veran_ort" SonSort="5" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/OperatorPhone" >
 <Position Row="3" Col="16" Len="5" />
  <Son Name="veran_tel" SonSort="6" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/OperatorPhoneNo" >
 <Position Row="3" Col="23" Len="20" />
  <Son Name="veran_tel_nr" SonSort="7" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/OperatorFax" >
 <Position Row="3" Col="44" Len="4" />
  <Son Name="veran_fax" SonSort="8" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/OperatorFaxNo" >
 <Position Row="3" Col="50" Len="10" />
  <Son Name="veran_fax_nr" SonSort="9" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/OperatorEmail" >
 <Position Row="4" Col="16" Len="6" />
  <Son Name="veran_email" SonSort="10" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/OperatorEmailAddr" >
 <Position Row="4" Col="23" Len="34" />
  <Son Name="veran_email_adr" SonSort="11" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/BookingNoStart" >
 <Position Row="6" Col="11" Len="13" />
  <Son Name="vorgangsnr_start" SonSort="12" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/BookingNoOperator" >
 <Position Row="6" Col="24" Len="12" />
  <Son Name="vorgangsnr_veran" SonSort="13" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/Headline" >
 <Position Row="6" Col="44" Len="30" />
  <Son Name="ueberschrift_rbe" SonSort="14" />
  <Printtype Big="1" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/Copy" >
 <Position Row="7" Col="44" Len="36" />
  <Son Name="kopie" SonSort="15" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/BookingDate" >
 <Position Row="8" Col="16" Len="10" />
  <Son Name="buchungsdatum" SonSort="16" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/BookingTime" >
 <Position Row="8" Col="28" Len="5" />
  <Son Name="buchungsuhrzeit" SonSort="17" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/InvoiceNo" >
 <Position Row="8" Col="44" Len="14" />
  <Son Name="rechnungsnr" SonSort="18" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/Number" >
 <Position Row="8" Col="59" Len="10" />
  <Son Name="nummer" SonSort="19" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/VestingDate" >
 <Position Row="9" Col="16" Len="10" />
  <Son Name="leistungsbeginn" SonSort="20" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/From" >
 <Position Row="9" Col="47" Len="10" />
  <Son Name="vom" SonSort="21" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/Time" >
 <Position Row="9" Col="59" Len="5" />
  <Son Name="zeit" SonSort="22" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/Page" >
 <Position Row="9" Col="68" Len="5" />
  <Son Name="seite" SonSort="23" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/IndicatorSupplement" >
 <Position Row="10" Col="2" Len="78" />
  <Son Name="hinweis_beiblatt" SonSort="24" />
  <Printtype Italic="1" />
  </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/IndicatorInsolvency" >
 <Position Row="11" Col="2" Len="78" />
  <Son Name="hinweis_insolvenz" SonSort="25" />
  <Printtype Italic="1" />
  </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/FreeFormatLine" >
 <Position Row="13" Col="2" Len="78" />
  <Son Name="frei_format_zeile" SonSort="26"  MaxOccurs="40" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/ProtectionPackage" >
 <Position Row="54" Col="2" Len="56" />
  <Son Name="text_schutzpaket" SonSort="27" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/PrintNo" >
 <Position Row="57" Col="41" Len="2" />
  <Son Name="druckversuche" SonSort="28" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/StaffNo" >
 <Position Row="58" Col="16" Len="4" />
  <Son Name="expedient" SonSort="29" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/CostCenter" >
 <Position Row="58" Col="21" Len="3" />
  <Son Name="kostenstelle" SonSort="30" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/OrderNo" >
 <Position Row="58" Col="25" Len="4" />
  <Son Name="auftrag" SonSort="31" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/SRZAgency" >
 <Position Row="58" Col="30" Len="6" />
  <Son Name="rz_ag" SonSort="32" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/SRZOffice" >
 <Position Row="58" Col="37" Len="3" />
  <Son Name="rz_bst" SonSort="33" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/PhoneLabel" >
 <Position Row="60" Col="6" Len="5" />
  <Son Name="tel" SonSort="34" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/PhoneNo" >
 <Position Row="60" Col="12" Len="20" />
  <Son Name="tel_nr" SonSort="35" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/CustomerTitle" >
 <Position Row="61" Col="6" Len="30" />
  <Son Name="kundenadr_titel" SonSort="36" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/CustomerName" >
 <Position Row="62" Col="6" Len="30" />
  <Son Name="kundenadr_name" SonSort="37" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/TravelAgencyAddr_1" >
 <Position Row="62" Col="38" Len="33" />
  <Son Name="reisebuero_adr_1" SonSort="38" />
  <Printtype Tight="1" />
  </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/CustomerStreet" >
 <Position Row="63" Col="6" Len="30" />
  <Son Name="kundenadr_str" SonSort="39" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/TravelAgencyAddr_2" >
 <Position Row="63" Col="38" Len="33" />
  <Son Name="reisebuero_adr_2" SonSort="40" />
  <Printtype Tight="1" />
  </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/CustomerAddOn" >
 <Position Row="64" Col="6" Len="30" />
  <Son Name="kundenadr_zusatz" SonSort="41" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/TravelAgencyAddr_3" >
 <Position Row="64" Col="38" Len="33" />
  <Son Name="reisebuero_adr_3" SonSort="42" />
  <Printtype Tight="1" />
  </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/CustomerCity" >
 <Position Row="65" Col="6" Len="34" />
  <Son Name="kundenadr_ort" SonSort="43" />
 </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/TravelAgencyAddr_4" >
 <Position Row="65" Col="38" Len="33" />
  <Son Name="reisebuero_adr_4" SonSort="44" />
  <Printtype Tight="1" />
  </Field>
<Field Name="SRBE/TravelAgencyAddr_5" >
 <Position Row="66" Col="38" Len="33" />
  <Son Name="reisebuero_adr_5" SonSort="45" />
  <Printtype Tight="1" />
  </Field>
   </Interface>
  </Mask>
 </STARTMasks>
</Repository>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has

```
    <xsl:call-template name="common"></xsl:call-template>

    <!-- check if mask is an SRBE -->
    <xsl:if test="$mask = 'SRBE'">
        <!-- iterate over all Field elements -->
        <xsl:for-each select="$path/Field">
            <!-- set variable fieldName with exploded Field Name -->
            <xsl:variable name="fieldName">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(./@Name, '/')"></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:variable>

            <!-- switch case start if maxoccurs is set or not -->
            <xsl:choose>
                <!-- if maxoccurs is set and greater then 1 -->
                <xsl:when test="./Son/@MaxOccurs and ./Son/@MaxOccurs > 1">

                    <!-- manually field sets -->
                    <xsl:if test="$fieldName = 'FreeFormatLine'">
                        <xsl:call-template name="tablePageBreak">
                            <xsl:with-param name="fieldName"><xsl:value-of select ="$fieldName"/></xsl:with-param>
                            <xsl:with-param name="wrapperName">Line</xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>
```

where the first `call-template name="common"` creates the `xsl:stylesheet` root element and then the other code obviously creates other elements outside of the `xsl:stylesheet` element. So basically all that code following `call-template name="common"` needs to be put into that templated named `common`, inside of `<xsl:element name="xsl:stylesheet">...</xsl:element>`.